# Given one side and its opposite angle of a triangle, find its maximum and minimum perimeter

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Tried using the cosine rule and triangle inequality.
but can't figure out a way to have a function in terms of $c$ and $\cos \hat{c}$ where $\hat{c}$ is the angle opposite the side $c$.

$c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab \cos \hat{c}$

let's call $\gamma = \cos \hat{c} $

now $c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab \gamma$ where $c,\gamma$ are fixed, but I can't find a way to express $a+b$ in terms of $\gamma$ and $c$.

The minimum can not be less than $2c$ by triangle inequality but the additional restriction of the angle should not let it to be equal to $2c$, also the constriction of the angle should put a constraint on sum of $a,b$.

Edit1 : fixed the wrong sign in the law of cosines.

Comment: You have a wrong sign in your statement of the Law of Cosines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the known side and angle $a$ and $\alpha$. Then, use the sine rule to get

$$\frac{b+c}a = \frac{\sin\beta+\sin\gamma}{\sin\alpha}
=\csc\frac\alpha2\>\cos\frac{\beta-\gamma}2$$

Note

$$\sin\frac\alpha2=\cos\frac{180-\alpha}2\le\cos\frac{\beta-\gamma}2\le 1$$

then,

$$1\le\frac{b+c}a \le \csc\frac\alpha2$$

Thus, the maximum sum is $a(1+\csc\frac\alpha2)$ with $\beta=\gamma$, and the minimum sum is $2a$ when $ \beta\>\text{or}\gamma \> \rightarrow 0$.